# What is the large blank area between the formula bar and the grid?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-365

I have a problem with Excel rendering a large blank area between the formula bar and the grid.

1. What is this area called? It's difficult to search for solutions without knowing what it actually is.
2. How can i get rid of it? Left and right clicking does nothing. I couldn't find any way to resize it or drag it.

[image: Excel blank area]

Some extra background information:

1. The xls file is generated by an excel library for php called Spreadsheet_Excel_Writer
2. In the same file i could add a new worksheet and the new one looks completely normal. This makes me think that the problem is in the worksheet and not the whole file.

Edit:
the file https://easyupload.io/1gj79b

Comment: Are there split windows or row anchors in the affected sheet. That is what it looks like because of the left hand row numbers.

Comment: @John there are neither split windows nor anchors. The whole worksheet is basically blank. the "dsf" string is just something i typed directly in excel.

Comment: I am not sure then. May be related to the library you used. Otherwise I cannot say.

Comment: Would it be possible to post online this spreadsheet? If you have more than one monitor, try dragging the Excel window to the other one.

Comment: @harrymc i've uploaded the file.

Comment: @harrymc i've already come across the solution with multiple monitors but it doesn't help

Comment: Sorry, I never saw anything like this before. I can't help, but maybe somebody else can now. Note: Your upload service is horrible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's an outline (I believe a column outline to be more specific), see screenshot to clear it [image: ribbon navigation]

Comment: thank you @gns100, it worked!